# How to use Reorderable Listview by drag and drop it by leading icon?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hi I want `ReorderableListView` in my code But by default ReorderableListView was reordered by drag and dropping the `icon` in the trailing,

But in my case I want to reorder the items by using leading icon. I don't know how to achieve it please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ReorderableDragStartListener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ReorderableDragStartListener-class.html) that will recognize the start of a drag on the wrapped widget by a PointerDownEvent, and immediately initiate dragging the wrapped item to a new location in a reorderable list

according to [example of buildDefaultDragHandles](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView/buildDefaultDragHandles.html) you can use:

```
class ReorderList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReorderList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ReorderList> createState() => _ReorderListState();
}

class _ReorderListState extends State<ReorderList> {
  final List<int> _items = List<int>.generate(50, (int index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableListView(
      buildDefaultDragHandles: false, //<-- set this to false to avoid build draghandle
      children: <Widget>[
        for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index++)
          ListTile(
            key: Key(index.toString()), //<-- use key
            title: Text(_items[index].toString()),
            leading: ReorderableDragStartListener( //<-- add this to leading
              index: index,
              child: Icon(Icons.tiktok),
            ),
          )
      ],
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        setState(() {
          if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
            newIndex -= 1;
          }
          final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
          _items.insert(newIndex, item);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

result be like:

[image: result]